# How to run two functions on AlertDialog Positive button click?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I am new in android, I created a alertdialog in my project that is basic and it has just [a message and one POSITIVE BUTTON and one NEGATIVE BUTTON] the message is a question that asks [Do you want to sign out from account?] and by pressing the NEGATIVE BUTTON closes the alertdialog, and by pressing the POSITIVE BUTTON it also closes the alertdialog and do nothing. I want to NEGATIVE BUTTON just close the alertdialog same as it does, but When I press the POSITIVE BUTTON it do two works for me [1- sign out from app and 2- start my activity which is called LoginActivity.kt]

Note : I  already do that two works by another layout that is activity_sign_out.xml that contains a button for doing that two works. but I want to do that two works  when alertdialog is showing just by pressing POSITIVE BUTTON.

I hope my question be clear for you.

I tryed to make that but it does'nt work, here is my codes :

1- my alertdialog :

```
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.res.Configuration
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import java.util.*

class DashboardActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
private lateinit var binding: ActivityDashboardBinding
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    loadLocale()
    binding = ActivityDashboardBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)
    val drawerLayout = findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawerLayout)
    val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
    val navView = findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.nav_view)
    val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.open,R.string.close)
    toggle.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled = true
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()
    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when(it.itemId){
            R.id.itmSignOut ->startActivity(Intent(this,SignOut::class.java))
            R.id.itmLanguage ->showChangeLanguageDialog()
            R.id.itmProfile ->basicAlert()
        }
        true
    }
}
private fun basicAlert(){
    val positiveButtonClick = { _: DialogInterface, _: Int -> }
    val negativeButtonClick = { _: DialogInterface, _: Int -> }
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    with(builder) {
        setMessage(R.string.do_you_want_to_sign_out_from_your_my_conquer_account)
        setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, ({ _: DialogInterface, _: Int ->
            positiveButtonClick
            auth.signOut()
            startActivity(Intent(this,LoginActivity::class.java))
            finish()
        }))
        setNegativeButton(R.string.no, negativeButtonClick)
        show()
    }
}
```

2- my SignOut.kt :

```
class SignOut : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
private lateinit var binding: ActivitySignOutBinding
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivitySignOutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_out)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)
    initData()
}
private fun initData(){
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    setUserEmail()
    clickListener()
}
private fun clickListener(){
    binding.btnSignOut.setOnClickListener{
        auth.signOut()
        startActivity(Intent(this,LoginActivity::class.java))
        finish()
    }
}
private fun getCurrentUserEmail():String? {
    return auth.currentUser?.email
}
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
private fun setUserEmail(){
    binding.tvUserEmail.text = "Welcome "+getCurrentUserEmail()
}
}
```

3- and the activity_sign_out.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SignOut">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvUserEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/welcome"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSignOut"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:text="@string/sign_out"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.8"
        tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck,TextContrastCheck" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

finally after running the app and coding for fixing it, I added the **auth.signOut()
startActivity(Intent(this,LoginActivity::class.java))
finish()** to my Alertdialog but it shows the errors for red Intent : [None of the following functions can be called with the argument supplied.

- (Content!, Class<*>!)defined in android.content.Intent
- (String!, Uri!)defined in android.content.Intent]

thank you for helping me! take care.

Comment: The way you're using the `positiveButtonClick` lambda is incorrect. And it seems to me like it serves no purpose, so you should just remove it.

Comment: Also, you haven't shown us which class `basicAlert` is a member of.

Comment: I just edited my question and added the class which alertdialog is its member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in Android Studio, `this` within the `with` block refers to the `AlertDialog.Builder` instance. To refer to the Activity you must say so explictly:

```
setPositiveButton(R.string.yes) { _: DialogInterface, _: Int ->
    auth.signOut()
    startActivity(Intent(this@DashboardActivity, LoginActivity::class.java))
    finish()
}
```